# Code First, many to many with additional fields dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, code-first

I have a `Playlist` class and a `Song` class in MVC4.

Rules:

- A Song can be in 0 or more playlists.
- A Playlist can contain 0 or more songs.

So what I did was create this:

```
public class Playlist
    {
        public int PlaylistID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<PlaylistSongs> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Song
    {
        public int SongID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SongArtURL { get; set; }

        public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public IList<PlaylistSongs> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
        public IList<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlaylistSongs
    {
        public int PlaylistID { get; set; }
        public int SongID { get; set; }

        public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
        public virtual Song Song { get; set; }

        public int NumberVotes { get; set; }
    }
```

And I also have overridden `OnModelCreating` as such:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<PlaylistSongs>()
                          .HasKey(cp => new { cp.SongID, cp.PlaylistID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Playlist>()
                        .HasMany(c => c.PlaylistSongs)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.SongID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Song>()
                        .HasMany(p => p.PlaylistSongs)
                        .WithRequired()
                        .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.PlaylistID);
        }
```

However, problem. Imagine if I want to create a `Song` which initially isn't attached to any `Playlist` (which works fine) and then add that Song to a Playlist. Since Playlist doesn't contain a list of Songs, but instead a list of PlaylistSongs, how would I do that?

What I want is to:

- Create a list of Songs (independently)
- Add that list of Songs to a Playlist
- Code First Migrations Seed method would then create the association needed automatically in the PlaylistSongs table.
- I could then let people vote on the Songs in a certain Playlist.
- The field `NumberVotes` would change accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating songs independently, then creating new `PlaylistSong` objects, adding those to the `PlaylistSongs` property on `Playlist`, and saving changes to database?

Comment: I dont have the full picture of what you want to create, but does a `song` realy need to know in which `playlists` it is?
You could remove the `PlayListSong` class then, and keep the vote count on the `song`, if that is ok in your design?

Comment: @Raf Yes it does, because each week there are different Playlists and a song can have different votes each week.

Comment: @HTX9 Yes, it throws up an error `Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Project1.Models.Song_PlaylistSongs' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.`

Comment: Add an ID field to the PlayListSong class and make the Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Data Anotations instead. Adding an Identity field to the `PlaylistSong` class.

```
    public class PlayList
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<PlayListSong> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayListSong
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PlayListID { get; set; }
        public int SongID { get; set; }

        public virtual PlayList Playlist { get; set; }
        public virtual Song Song { get; set; }

        public int NumberVotes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Song
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SongArtURL { get; set; }

        //public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        //public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        public IList<PlayListSong> PlaylistSongs { get; set; }
       // public IList<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```